# Is there a way to replace a string in a specific file upon calling Eclipse build?

Tags: eclipse, replace, build

I need to update an external file removing specific content upon performing eclipse build for a Java project.
I want perform this automatically before eclipse performs the build. 
A note, Build automatically is disabled. 
I am using Eclipse Kepler SR2.
Thank you.

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm (in your case, the Ant project builder has to be the first project builder)

Comment: Appreciate the prompt replay @howlger, I am looking for something that can be workspace specific and can be kept off source control and releases. Something for a dev environment only. Thanks. But I will check it out and see. Thanks.

Comment: An Ant project builder requires at least two files: a `build.xml` file which can be located outside the workspace and the `.project` in the project folder which defines the name, the natures and the builders of the project. So make sure, not to check-in the changed `.project` file.

Comment: Looks like i am going with solution and I keep in mind these points.
Thank you @howlger